# How do you duplicate a shell instance in Unix?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

My specific problem is the following: I am using Mac OS X with the Visor app for terminal. This lets me do cool pop-in/out stuff with terminal for quick access. The problem is, I lose the ability to move the window around and re-size it, something that becomes important when I start opening up multiple buffers in emacs and want to view some at the same time in a window larger than 80 wide.

Does anyone know how to duplicate a shell window/instance, so that a new window appears with the same history, current working dir, aliases, etc...? Even more specifically, can this be done in Mac OS X such that the new window is in a different "style", (basic, pro, sands, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Visor, but simply using a terminal emulator such as screen might give you what you need.  From a terminal, invoke 'screen'.  That will give you a shell prompt.  From another terminal, invoke 'screen -x'.  Now each terminal will be attached to the same shell, with the same history, etc.   See screen(1) for details.

Comment: My only problem with screen is that it destroys the emacs shortcut C-a, not only in emacs, but also on the command line for going to the start of line. If only screen shortcuts were configurable...

Comment: @emish Screen is configurable.  You can change the escape key with -e